# Month Year In String to Date Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/yyyy");
LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(entryOne.getKey(), dateFormat)
```

Getting exception

> Text '03/2018' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor:

How to parse this string and convert to Date using Java 8 having default first day of the month. Something what we do using.

```
TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two choices for converting a `MM/yyyy` string into a `LocalDate`:

- Parse as `YearMonth` then convert to `LocalDate`:

  ```
  String date = "04/2018";
  DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/yyyy");
  YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.parse(date, dateFormat);
  LocalDate parsedDate = yearMonth.atDay(1);
  System.out.println(parsedDate); // prints: 2018-04-01
  ```
- Use a `DateTimeFormatter` with a default day-of-month defined:

  ```
  String date = "04/2018";
  DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
          .appendPattern("MM/yyyy")
          .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
          .toFormatter();
  LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(date, dateFormat);
  System.out.println(parsedDate); // prints: 2018-04-01
  ```

Comment: DateTimeFormatterBuilder#toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH) is a good practice.

Comment: @SparkOn If you suggest to use something like `.toFormatter(Locale.US)`, then you should also suggest to use `.ofPattern("MM/yyyy", Locale.US)`, but it doesn't affect the result, regardless of your default locale. Now, if pattern displayed month *name*, the locale would matter, but since only numbers are displayed/parsed, locale doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what works for me:

```
String dateAsString = "03/2018";
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/yyyy");
DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(dateAsString);
LocalDateTime ldt = new LocalDateTime(dt);
int dayOfWeek = ldt.getDayOfWeek(); //has value of 4 since Thursday was the first day of March
```

Comment: Lemme guess, using Joda-Time? Asking because I think the question used `java.time`, which may be considered the successor of Joda-Time.